# Replace nonnumeric characters excluding unicode

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

I have this regex which replaces everything apart from alphanumeric, whitespaces and dashes.

```
str.replace(/[^\w\s-]+/g, '')
```

A) How could I make it exclude the unicode words in the `str` ? 
Should I put manually all the `!#$%`etc. symbols I want to exclude?

B) Also if I want to get rid the emoji (since I would allow the other unicode) and want to keep only the other language's words?

Comment: Item A: `str.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\s-]/g, '');`?

Comment: Define “unicode words”. What exactly do you want to exclude (apparently, from the set of characters to be removed)?

Comment: Can you give some examples which emoji you are referring to?
Some of these? Which? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji#In_the_Unicode_standard

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela for example "ιδέα" is a "unicode word" in greek characters which in unicode is: `'\u03b9\u03b4\u03ad\u03b1'`. If I try the above `.replace()` I will get an empty string as a result. Example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KP55G/)

Comment: An example is not a definition. For programming, you need a definition. And you get an empty string because of the way `\w` has been defined (it only matches certain Ascii characters).

Answer (score 0):

if you know the character set range you can exclude those. this will exclude all the non numeric chars

```
 str = str.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '');
```

Comment: This would remove much more characters than the code in the question. The purpose is apparently to remove *less*.

Answer (score 0):

The safest way to do it is to include the list of characters that you do not want to match in your character set, as you described in `A`.

- `^` = negative match
- `\w` = shortcut for `a-zA-Z0-9`,
- `\s` = (space),
- `!`, `#`, `$`, `%`, and `-` = those specific characters

The negative match caused the character class to match anything not in the list, and you can leave off the `+` to match single characters you want to remove:

**Input**: `str = 'this is a test )(*&^%$#@!~';`

**Regex**: `str.replace(/[^\w\s!#$%-]/g, '');`

**Result**: `this is a test %$#!`

See: http://regex101.com/r/nD4wL1